# why i cant use require to load local image? REACT

Tags: reactjs, webpack

im trying to use require to load the image, but it isnt working, even the image is in the same folder as the file, if i import it it works, but using require it doenst,

works if i do this:

```
import Image from "./prueba.jpg";

<img src = {Image} .../>
```

doesnt work using require:

```
<img src = {require("./prueba.jpg")} .../>
```

this is my project structure:

[image]

[image]

as you can see i want to use the image prueba in the file Profile, but cant use it with require, need to do it this way cause it will load the image from the db

this is my webpack config, i did this following a video

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: __dirname + "/src/public",
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    resolve: {
        fallback: {
            "crypto": false,
        }
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                use: "babel-loader",
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                use: "file-loader",
                test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
                test: /\.css$/i,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            }
        ],
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your syntax is not correct - Miss `closing curly braces`
Update img tag
`<img src = {require("./prueba.jpg")} .../>`